# Looping through nested JSON array, getting children with same object model

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON response that looks like the following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 1,
        "message": "Hello",
        "children": [
            {
                "id": 7,
                "user_id": 2,
                "message": "Hi",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "user_id": 3,
                        "message": "Hey",
                        "children": [

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": 4,
        "message": "Ahoy",
        "children": [

        ]
    }
]
```

I already have the model created (`Message.java`). The children can be retrieved by calling `getChildren()`. The response is saved in a list `List<Message> messages`.

How can I loop through this JSON array to get the contents of each child until there is no child left? Is this possible without a recursive function?

Comment: i am still a bit confused about what you want to do. can you elaborate a bit what exactly you are trying with this json? and how exactly you want to store it?

Answer (score 1):

I Assume you have List messages :

Here is how you can browse through all children with both recursion and iterative way :

```
List<Message> messages = //you already have that

System.out.println("Using Recusion : ");

for (Message message : messages) {
    printMessage(message);
}

System.out.println("Using Iterative : ");

Stack<Message> stack = new Stack<>();
stack.addAll(messages);

while (!stack.empty()) {
    Message item = stack.pop();
    System.out.println(item.getId() + ":" + item.getUser_id() + ":" + item.getMessage());
    for (Message chidren : item.getChildren()) {
        stack.push(chidren);
    }
}
```

and here is the printMessage method :

```
public static void printMessage(Message pmessage) {
    System.out.println(pmessage.getId() + ":" + pmessage.getUser_id() + ":" + pmessage.getMessage());
    for (Message message : pmessage.getChildren()) {
        printMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public void printJsonObject(JSONObject jsonObj) {
            for (String keyStr : jsonObj.keySet()) {
                Object keyvalue = jsonObj.get(keyStr);

                //Print key and value
                System.out.println("key: "+ keyStr + " value: " + keyvalue);

                //for nested objects iteration if required
                if (keyvalue instanceof JSONObject)
                    printJsonObject((JSONObject)keyvalue);
            }

        }
```